# Cordova platforms/ios/www/ contains old files

Tags: cordova

I have had this problem with my Cordova/Phonegap app for weeks, that when I push an update to Itunes Connect and TestFlight, it doesn't update. Have pushed new updates like 5 times to no avail. Still same old app.

Today I discovered that platforms/ios/www/ contains the old files which would explain why it doesn't update.

But why would it not contain the correct files? How can I get it to behave correctly?

Comment: are you running `cordova prepare` or `cordova build` after you complete changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making changes to outer www folder...
So You Need Build Your Project Before Running You App..
Here is the Code. Just run in your command Line:

```
$ cordova build android or ios
```